# Git on OSX is cloning symlinks as plaintext files

Tags: git, macos

I have a git repo that has a symlink checked into it. When I check it out on OSX the file is created as a plaintext file instead of a symlink (using git version 2.7.4)

Running ls -lah gives me:

```
$ ls -lah
-rw-r--r--   1 user  group    30B 11 May 17:40 symlink
```

Running on the same repo on a linux server (with git 1.9.1) gives me what I expect:

```
$ ls -lah
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user  group    30B 11 May 17:42 symlink -> ../symlink/path
```

The file is correctly checked in as a symlink in the repo (mode 120000)

```
$ git ls-tree --full-tree -l HEAD
120000 blob 8cbd91679559387b3ea5f5596b9fa307d32d8420      30    symlink
```

Also, git status doesn't pick up any changes. If I re-create the symlinks, git status still doesn't pick up any changes

Comment: I can't reproduce, either locally or using a repo that was created on Linux and cloned to a Mac over ssh. Can you provide a reproducible example? Or perhaps provide some more information on how you are accessing the repo from OS X. I assume that your local (Mac) file system is HFS+?

Comment: Cloning this repo on OSX 10.11.1 with git 2.7.4 doesn't work https://github.com/frankh/symlink-breaking

My HD filesystem is "Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)"

Comment: I'm using git 2.3.0 and it's working just fine. It seems to me that you may have a git configuration option set that is causing symlinks to "fail" (what does `git config --get core.symlinks` return?).

Comment: Yep that was it, core.symlinks was set to false for some reason. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git has a configuration option that will check out symlinks as regular files:

> *core.symlinks*
>
> If false, symbolic links are checked out as small plain files that contain the link text.

([source](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html))

Make sure that that option isn't `false`. You can check for it with this:

```
$ git config --get core.symlinks
```